# Error in MCMCglmm

Tags: r, mcmc, hierarchical-bayesian

I'm having some troubling running a mixed model in MCMCglmm. It works fine when I try to run it as a linear regression:

```
Model.Fit = MCMCglmm(Y~X1, random = ~Cluster, data = DataSet)
```

But I can't seem to get it to run a logistic or ordinal regression:

```
Model.Fit = MCMCglmm(Y~X1, random = ~Cluster, family = "ordinal" data = DataSet)
```

It gives me the following error message:

Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
In addition: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: 'family'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If anyone else is looking for the answer, I've worked it out. MCMCglmm expects the data frame to have class "data.frame". Mine also had classes "tbl" and "tbl_df". Setting class to only "data.frame" solved the problem.